# Google Tag Manager External Links with Multiple Domains

Tags: events, google-analytics, tracking, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

All tutorials I have found for setting up external link click (exit tracking) within Google Tag Manager have suggested you create a firing rule such as the one in the image below.

This is great when I know what the domain name will be, however, as I am working with multiple domains I need the external link click trigger to fire on every Element URL that is not equal to the hostname.

I have tried entering the variable {{Page Hostname}} instead of yourdomain.com but that does not seem to work.

Has anyone else had this issue? Google doesn't seem to yield a similar use case.

[External Link Clicks Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQVFM.png)

Comment: Did you find a solution? I've exactly the same solution. I'm thinking of adding a class to the link element by adding some javascript. But there should be a better solution right?